# Insertion at a specific location in a singular linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Actually i am trying to insert a node at a specific location but it errors when i run the insertloc() funcion

The problem is in insertloc() function

```
void linked :: insertloc()
{  
  int loc;
  cout<<"\nEnter the location where you want to insert , starting from 1";
  cin>>loc;
  node *temp=new node;
  node *temp1;
  cout<<"\nEnter the info part";
  cin>>temp->info;
  loc-=1;


  if(loc==0)
  {
    temp->next=start;
    start=temp;
  }
  else
  {
    temp1=start;
    for(int i=0;i<=loc-1;i++)
    {
      temp1=temp1->next;
      cout<<temp->info<<"   ";
    }
    temp->next=temp1->next;
    temp1->next=temp;
  }
```

}

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line.

Comment: What do you mean compiler crashes? What compiler you are using?

Comment: There is no check that the list is long enough in your for loop.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that "the compiler crashes when i run the funcion". Is this your program or the compiler which crashes ?

Comment: Compiler (TCWIN 4.5) just stops execution with a error.            _@aisbaa  @hivert  Sorry to say compiler crashes_.

Comment: Care to share what the error is?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you do not check whether temp1->next is equal to NULL in this code snippet

else
  {

```
temp1=start;
for(int i=0;i<=loc-1;i++)
{
  temp1=temp1->next;
  cout<<temp->info<<"   ";
}
```

Also the condition of the loop is invalid. It has to be `i < loc-1`

I would write it the following way

```
temp1=start;
int i = 0;

while ( ++i < loc && temp1->next ) temp1 = temp1->next;

if ( i == loc )
{
  temp->next = temp1->next;
  temp1->next = temp;
}
```

Also I would declare the function as

```
bool linked :: insertloc( size_t n );
```

And all this code that asks to enter a location I would exclude from the function

```
  int loc;
  cout<<"\nEnter the location where you want to insert , starting from 1";
  cin>>loc;
  node *temp=new node;
  node *temp1;
  cout<<"\nEnter the info part";
  cin>>temp->info;
```